# Problem using debugging with c language and cygwin

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've installed visual studio code version 1.74.0 and I'm using it for some testing and development with c language and Cygwin, for building and running works fine, but the problem arises when I try to use the debugger, I have this message "The editor could not be opened because the file was not found", basically it's not able to find the source file where there are also the breakpoints.

The correct source file is: "C:\Users\PG005856\Documents\clanguage\projects\ctest\test.c" but it tries to find in this path :
"C:\Users\PG005856\Documents\clanguage\projects\ctest\C\Users\PG005856\Documents\clanguage\projects\ctest\test.c"

It tries to recreate the same path inside the workspace, this is my launch.json file :

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/test.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:/MyProgram/cygwin64/bin/gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Anyone have any clue about this problem ? i've tried to search online but with no luck.

Thanks,
Tommaso.

Comment: Did you check: [Using GCC with MinGW](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) ?

Comment: Hi,i'm using gcc from cygwin,  mingw-w64 if i'm not wrong didn't have the regex posix library.

Comment: Ok found the problem was a bug on gdb rolling back to gdb 9.2-1 solve the problem

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because : "the problem was a bug on gdb rolling back to gdb 9.2-1 solve the problem"